# how to display auto increment data form mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

In my university database project I have an auto increment field roll number in my SQL. What I want is that when new admission take place and a student record is inserted it displays all finds on same page including roll number. However despite my best efforts all it returns 0 in roll number.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("conection error");
mysqli_select_db($con, "hamdard university") or die("dbase error");

if (isset($_POST['subbtn'])) {

    $r      = "SELECT RollNo FROM admission_form";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $r);
    if (mysqli_query($con, $r)) {
        $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    }


    $n = $_POST['txtname'];
    $f = $_POST['txtfac'];
    $s = $_POST['txtsem'];

    $sql = "insert into admission_form(name,faculty,semester)values                ('$n','$f','$s')";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql);



    echo "<table border=1>
            <th>RollNo</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Faculty</th>
            <th>Semester</th>";



    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $last_id;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $n;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $f;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $s;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<br>";


}
?>

<html>

<head></head>

<body>
    <form name="f1" action="" method="POST">
        RollNo:
        <input type="text" name="txtroll" readonly> Name:
        <input type="text" name="txtname"> Faculty:
        <input type="text" name="txtfac"> Semester:
        <input type="text" name="txtsem">
        <input type="submit" value="done" name="subbtn">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: fiends? Perhaps you mean friends? If so, how are friendships recorded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need get $last_id after INSERT query

```
$sql="insert into admission_form(name,faculty,semester)values ...
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misplaced insert query. Change it as:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")or die("conection error");
mysqli_select_db($con,"hamdard university")or die("dbase error");

if(isset($_POST['subbtn']))
{

 $sql="insert into admission_form(name,faculty,semester)values                ('$n','$f','$s')";

if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) 
{
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
}


$n=$_POST['txtname'];
$f=$_POST['txtfac'];
$s=$_POST['txtsem'];



$r="SELECT RollNo FROM admission_form";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $r);


echo        "<table border=1>
        <th>RollNo</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Faculty</th>
        <th>Semester</th>";



    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $last_id;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $n;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $f;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $s;
    echo "</td>";   

    echo "<br>";


}
?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<form name="f1" action="" method="POST">

RollNo:<input type="text" name="txtroll" readonly>
Name:<input type="text" name="txtname">
Faculty:<input type="text" name="txtfac">
Semester:<input type="text" name="txtsem">
<input type="submit" value="done" name="subbtn">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(SQLI_SERVER, MYSQLI_USER, MYSQLI_PWD, MYSQLI_DBNAME);
if ($result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO admission_form(name, facility,semester) VALUES..) {
    echo 'The ID is: '.$mysqli->insert_id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems in this page.

1. As stated before, the INSER query must be before the select.
2. If you do "SELECT RollNo FROM admission_form" you will get ALL existing RollNo in admission_form and not the lastest one. If this is an int with auto increment (that seams to be) you should do "SELECT max(RollNo) FROM admission_form".
3. You don't need to do the above select, as mysqli_insert_id get the ID inserted in the last query.
4. You might not see the result in your table because it is on HTML head, but it should be in the body of the page.
5. The table you create is not "closed".

You should be good to go with the code bellow.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD></HEAD>
<BODY>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")or die("conection error");
mysqli_select_db($con,"hamdard university")or die("dbase error");

if(isset($_POST['subbtn']))
{
  $n=$_POST['txtname'];
  $f=$_POST['txtfac'];
  $s=$_POST['txtsem'];

  $sql="insert into admission_form(name,faculty,semester) values                ('$n','$f','$s')";

  if (mysqli_query($con, $r)) 
  {
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
  }

echo        "<table border=\"1\"><th>RollNo</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Faculty</th> <th>Semester</th>";

    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $last_id;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $n;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $f;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $s;
    echo "</td>";   

    echo "</tr></table>";


}
?>

<form name="f1" action="" method="POST">

RollNo:<input type="text" name="txtroll" readonly>
Name:<input type="text" name="txtname">
Faculty:<input type="text" name="txtfac">
Semester:<input type="text" name="txtsem">
<input type="submit" value="done" name="subbtn">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```